# How to continue iterating the next char in a for each loop in rust

Tags: loops, rust, token, lex

I am writing a simple tokenizer that will take an input from it's new function (which hopefully be removed in favor of a REPL) and spit back out the tokens associated with the css syntax.

Here is an example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Token {
    Selector,
    LBrace,
    RBrace,
    Property,
    Value,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Tokenizer {
    source: String,
    tokens: Vec<(Token, String)>,
}

impl Tokenizer {
    pub fn new(source: &str) -> Self {
        let source = source.to_string();

        for (i, c) in source.chars().enumerate() {
            if c == '.' {
                // This is where I am stuck.
            }
        }

        Self {
            source,
            tokens: vec![],
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tokens = Tokenizer::new(".example{}");
    println!("{:#?}", tokens);
}
```

Now my issue is that I want to iterate over the next characters until I meet one of `#` `'space'`, `.` but I have no idea how rust allows me to keep iterating until a condition is met. Is there a way to call the next character in the sequence?

Also if you do find anything wrong with this code in-terms of direction I am taking, please let me know. Thank you.

Here is a link to the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=68eff7e3e749f77beeac3cd4e866731a).

Comment: Maybe you want [`break`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#break-expressions) or [`continue`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#continue-expressions)?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a very broad question, I would refer to [servo's css-parser](https://github.com/servo/rust-cssparser/blob/master/src/tokenizer.rs).

Some functions that may come in handy:

- [`skip_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip_while) can skip elements in the beginning satisfying a certain predicate
- [`peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) creates an iterator able to look ahead

Instead of working on iterators, you could also work on slices (`&str`). This may be easier because an (plain old) iterator basically gives you access to *one element at a time* whereas a slice allows you to go back and forth as you wish (within reasonable bounds, of course).

Comment: Thank you for this. But could you explain what you mean by working with slices? And why?

Comment: @Zana instead of iterating over the string, you can write a loop (e.g. `while !source.is_empty() {}`) that removes tokens from the string by [slicing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#string-slices) it.